# Losing threejs context in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using **react-three-fiber** within **Next.js** and am rendering the component that holds the canvas and loads a glTF file via `useGLTFoader` using Next's `dynamic` import with disabled server side rendering.
When visiting / reloading the page the glTF is loaded and shown as expected.

My problem is, that when switching pages I get the following error:

> THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.

When navigating back to the page again, the model is not visible although the canvas is available and my component that takes a screenshot on a specified action is working correctly too (but does not show the model as well).

The component that holds the canvas and renders the glTF  is very basic looks like this:

```
export const Rendering = ({
  resourcePath,
}) => {
  const gltf = useGLTFLoader(resourcePath, false);

  return (
    <Canvas
      colorManagement
      shadowMap
      camera={{ position: new Vector3(1, 1, 1) }}
      pixelRatio={window.devicePixelRatio}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <MakeScreenshot />
      <primitive object={gltf.scene} position={[0, -1, 0} />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.8} />
      <pointLight intensity={1} position={[0, 6, 0]} />
    </Canvas>
  );
};
```

The import (as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)) is done like this:

```js
const Rendering = dynamic(() => import('../rendering/rendering'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why, but adding the prop `dispose={null}` to the `<primitive />` that renders the glTF scene, fixed the problem for me.

The `THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.` message still appears when switching pages, so that I assume, that it was not directly related to my problem.

My component is now specified like this:

```js
export const Rendering = ({
  resourcePath,
}) => {
  const gltf = useGLTFLoader(resourcePath, false);

  return (
    <Canvas
      colorManagement
      shadowMap
      camera={{ position: [1,1,1] }}
      pixelRatio={window.devicePixelRatio}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <MakeScreenshot />
      <primitive object={gltf.scene} position={[0, -1, 0]} dispose={null} />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.8} />
      <pointLight intensity={1} position={[0, 6, 0]} />
    </Canvas>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am having the same problem with next and react three fiber, did you find a solution?